# Firebase OnDisconnect and ".info/connected" issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a mobile game which has online/offline status of each player. Hence, we decide to integrate firebase as the solution. However, when we dig more, we find that many APIs are not as we expect.

Here is the brief concept about what we did.

1. We have a structure like

```
Presence: 
{
    UserID:
    {
        Unique Key1:
        {
            Online: True
        }
    }
}
```

2. When we initialize firebase, we push the node to realtime database. The code is like below.

```
_myPresenceRef = _presenceRef.Child(_oid).Push();
_myPresenceRef.OnDisconnect().RemoveValue().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
{
    if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled)
    {
        presenceData["Online"] = true;

        _myPresenceRef.SetValueAsync(presenceData);
    }
});
```

3. We also register connection value changed event in order to handle disconnect situation. Sample code as below.

```
private void _InitializeListeners()
{
    _connectionRef = db.GetReference(".info/connected");
    _connectionRef.ValueChanged += _OnConnectionValueChanged;
}

private void _OnConnectionValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var s = args.Snapshot;
    if (s == null)
        return;

    if ((bool) s.GetValue(false))
    {
        _myPresenceRef = _presenceRef.Child(_oid).Push();
        _myPresenceRef.OnDisconnect().RemoveValue().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled)
            {
                presenceData[Online] = true;
                _myPresenceRef.SetValueAsync(presenceData);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        _myPresenceRef = null;
    }
}
```

From above, the goal is that when user connect to the game, we push the presence data of user to realtime database. Meanwhile, we set "ondisconnect" to server to delete the presence data when the server finds the user is disconnected.

Everything works fine; however, things get strange when the id token expired. 
From what I know the id token would be expired for every hour and refresh automatically. I found there are three situations which are not expected.

1. When in unity editor, which we authorized by `SetEditorAuthUserId` with p12 key.
2. When in android background for an hour and then back to the app.
3. When in android background for an hour and close the app directly.

From above situations, even after close the app, the record in realtime database would not be deleted. That is the data lives in realtime database forever.

```
Presence: 
{
    UserID:
    {
        Unique Key1:
        {
            Online: True
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the `onDisconnect` event doesn't work anymore even when the id token is refreshed.

From what I have searching from the internet and official document, it shows that when server runs the `onDisconnect` event, it checks if the operation is still valid or not. If not, it wouldn't take any action.

Here are my questions

1. Do I understand correctly about the `onDisconnect` behavior? If not, could any one explain what happened?
2. If I am correct, how do people deal with the issue of `onDisconnect` when id token get refreshed.
3. It seems like "refreshing id token" would trigger `.info/connected` value changed. Is this expected? If so, why wouldn't it trigger `onDisconnect`?

Thanks for helping me in advance. Please let me know if there is anything unclear.

- Firebase Version: 6.0.0
- Unity Version: 2018.4.4f1

---

Update:

The root cause of why my `onDisconnect` is not working is that I have rule on my realtime database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "presence": {
        "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": true
      }
    },
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
  }
}
```

The `onDisconnect` do take action. However, when it runs `removeValue` operation, it got forbidden due to the ".write" rule, which needs authorized uid.

It sounds quite reasonable. But to my, it does not. It is too tricky. As a user, I expect when registering operation to 'onDisconnect' without any error. It should execute it no matter what happens later. Because at that moment, I am a authorized user.

Things get strange under some scenario. Let me explain more.

1. The app is in background on android platform. After the id token is expired, it triggers `".info/connected"` changed event. From the code, it would push a new node to presence and the `removeValue` operation wouldn't work due to `id token expiration`. It makes sense now.
2. The app is in foreground on android platform. After the id token is expired,
   it doesn't trigger `".info/connected"` changed event and 'onDisconnect' would not trigger, either. It just works like nothing happen behind.
3. The app is running on unity editor. After the id token is expired, it triggers `".info/connected"` changed event. From the code, it would push a new node to presence and the `removeValue` operation wouldn't work due to `id token expiration`.

From above scenario, it seems like firebase behavior is different from platform to platform, which is quite annoyed.

Comment: The `onDisconnected` handling of the Realtime Database has no knowledge of the active user, but of course the write operation must be allowed at the moment it happens (when the server detects that the connection is gone). Do you have any `.write` rules that could be rejecting the write operation from `onDisconnect`? In that case you'd never see the error message of course, since that write happens when the user is no longer connected. If you do have such rules, you might want to try relaxing them to see if they indeed are the cause of the problem you're having.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your reply. Yes, my rule for `.write` is `uid = auth.uid`. I believe it is the rule that forbids the operation but it is not intuitive that when I set `onDisconnect`, I do have the full privilege for `.write` . But when it executes the commnad, it got forbidden. Is it a reasonable design?

Comment: "If you do have such rules, you might want to try relaxing them to see if they indeed are the cause of the problem you're having." We're still troubleshooting here, as I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I will try that. But I think it takes time. Currently, I have no privilege for the rule. It takes time for me to build a new environment. By the way, thanks for you advice.

Comment: Finally I got the experiment result in unity editor. It is the rule that block my `delete opreration` in `onDisconnection`. However, relaxing  the rule seems like not an appropriate way to deal the issue, since it makes the data less security. I wonder if there are any other solution on this. By the way, still thanks for FrankvanPuffelen 's advice.